# How to get a "fieldcount" (like wordcount) on CouchDB/Cloudant?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb, word-count, cloudant

Trying to get a count of fields, just like the classic word count example. I thought this would be trivial...

[image]

but I got this useless result...

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":212785214}
]}
```

How can I get what I wanted... an inventory of all fields used in my documents, with a count of how many times they occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a count of each key in your document, create a "map" function like this:

```
function (doc) {
  var keys = Object.keys(doc);
  for(var i in keys) {
    emit(keys[i], null);
  }
}
```

and use the built in `_count` reducer.

You can then retrieve the grouped answer by accessing the view like so:

```
/mydb/_design/<designdocname>/_view/<viewname>?group_level=1
```

which will produce grouped keys and counts like this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"_id","value":4},
{"key":"_rev","value":4},
{"key":"a","value":3},
{"key":"c","value":1}
]}
```

Comment: worked like a charm but I got one surprise, I have many occurrences of an empty key ("") - what could it mean?